# leaflet geojson coordinates to array

Tags: leaflet

```js
var mymap = L.map('map').setView([53.7983587, -1.6191674], 11);
    mymap.createPane('labels');
    mymap.getPane('labels').style.zIndex = 650;
    mymap.getPane('labels').style.pointerEvents = 'none';

    var positron = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '©OpenStreetMap, ©CartoDB'
}).addTo(mymap);

var positronLabels = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_only_labels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '©OpenStreetMap, ©CartoDB',
        pane: 'labels'
}).addTo(mymap);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/adam97x/cjavcj1680vgz2sqshn70q5pg/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiYWRhbTk3eCIsImEiOiJjamF2Y2k1NmswYzhuMnZtazlpNXU2NDExIn0.RifBBI5nelL-4d21mkn7Wg', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'mapbox.streets'
    }).addTo(mymap);

        // control that shows state info on hover
    var info = L.control();

    info.onAdd = function (mymap) {
        this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
        this.update();
        return this._div;
    };

    info.update = function (props) {
        this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>Highlighted Postcode</h4>' +  (props ?
            '<b> Postcode: ' + props.Name
            : 'Hover over a state');
    };

    info.addTo(mymap);


function style(feature) {
    return {
        fillColor: 'grey',
        weight: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'white',
        dashArray: '3',
        fillOpacity: 0.5
    };
}

L.geoJson(statesdata, {style: style}).addTo(mymap);

    function highlightFeature(e) {
        var layer = e.target;

        layer.setStyle({
            weight: 5,
            opacity: 1,
            color: '#000',
            dashArray: '',
            fillOpacity: 0.7
        });

        if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
            layer.bringToFront();
        }

        info.update(layer.feature.properties);
    }

    var geojson;

    function resetHighlight(e) {
        geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
        info.update();
    }
        function zoomToFeature(e) {
    mymap.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
                var coords = layer.feature.geometry.coordinates;
                console.log(coords);
    }
    coords = []; //define an array to store coordinates
    function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        layer.on({
            mouseover: highlightFeature,
            mouseout: resetHighlight,
            click: zoomToFeature
        });
    }


    geojson = L.geoJson(statesdata, {
        style: style,
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature
    }).addTo(mymap);
    test = [];
geojson.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    layer.bindPopup(layer.feature.properties.Name);

});
```

```css
  body { margin:0; padding:0; }
  #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
  .info { padding: 6px 8px; font: 14px/16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background: white; background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8); box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); border-radius: 5px; } .info h4 { margin: 0 0 5px; color: #777; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>KML Data</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://project-adam97.c9users.io/asset/bd.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@turf/turf@5/turf.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-omnivore/v0.2.0/leaflet-omnivore.min.js'></script>

<div id='map'></div>


</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to output the geojson file's coordinates into an array upon clicking a sector (post code) of the map so i can flip them to lat,lng instead of lng,lat however I am struggling to do so.

```
function zoomToFeature(e) {
    mymap.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
                var coords = layer.feature.geometry.coordinates;
                console.log(coords);
}
```

I would have thought it is something along these lines however I am getting feature is not defined as a result in the console.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using them differently in my onEachFeature but I get the coordinates like this:

var coords = layer.feature.geometry.coordinates;

Without hacking at it, I believe you are just missing the word "layer" before feature.geometry.

Comment: Hi yeah that seems to have worked, however I'm actually trying to pull the coordinates into the array upon clicking a poly. I've tried to add "var coords = layer.feature.geometry.coordinates; into my ZoomToFeature however the console error becomes layer is not defined.

Comment: Your array would have worked you were missing "layer.feature.properties." You had "feature.properties. 

http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/Select/SelectPoints3.html 
Takes a click and finds sites within a distance of. and creates a new geojson layer. 
This creates an array and brings the points in as a layer and 
if I added

map.fitBounds(geojsonLayer.getBounds(), {padding: [12, 12]})

It would zoom to the selected set.

Comment: The link may help, the last four topics here are close. 
I use Turf to get features inside the polygon.
http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/